# Websocket for Android

Tags: java, android, ios, websocket

I am following https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java to implement websocket in android.

```
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://chat.socket.io");
        mSocket2 = IO.socket("https://v2.cloudtimer.nl:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mSocket.connect();

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(100000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            Log.v(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "mSocket.connected() : " + mSocket.connected()+", mSocket2.connected() : " + mSocket2.connected());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

And I am getting `mSocket.connected() : true, mSocket2.connected() : false` message. Which is `http://chat.socket.io` is connected but `https://v2.cloudtimer.nl:3000` doesn't connected. But `https://v2.cloudtimer.nl:3000` is connected in ios.

So I can't find where is the problem. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I only see one call to .connect() .?

Comment: @ABuckau , Good find bro. I have added... But still it doesn't get connected :(

Comment: Https: does the site actually support https? And does the socket class support https ?

Comment: I don't know bro.. :(

Comment: Try ws:// instead of https://

Comment: @ABuckau java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ws